# Can I replenish my dataset with unlabeled data?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, dataset

I have a database of time series data generated by giroscope sensor. A small part of the data is already labeled and used to fit the model. My strong assumption is that most of the samples left in this database are of the same class of movement. Can I use this data to replenish the model without manual labeling? What are the steps required?

Comment: Have you tried using various clustering algorithms?

Comment: Not yet. I've already trained my model with a small dataset, but I have a huge amount of unlabeled data. Can I use it somehow to replenish the dataset? What should I do after cluster analysis?

Comment: What does “replenish a model” means? Also, you might be interested in “semi-supervised learning”.

Comment: Try clustering and see if any cluster agrees strongly with the labels you already have. Then try some more clustering results and algorithms.

Comment: Thanks @GaëlLaurans. I think semi-supervised learning is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search term that could help you is: **semi-supervised modeling**

Here's a start: [Chapelle, Schölkopf, and Zien: Semi-Supervised Learning, MIT Press, 2006](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/semi-supervised-learning)

AFAIK, one of the most important assumptions for the semi-supervised strategies is that the class boundaries do actually have low sample density (cluster assumption). That is why you were asked about clustering your data.

If your model assumptions are correct, unlabeled data can help. However, if your assumptions are not quite met, the model may actually become worse:
[(Cozman and Cohen: Unlabeled Data Can Degrade Classification Performance of Generative Classifiers, HP Laboratories Palo Alto, 2001, HPL-2001-234)](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2001/HPL-2001-234.html)

Semi-supervised modeling cares about model *training* only. For *testing*, IMHO you need manually labelled data - otherwise the cluster assumption may create a "self-fulfilling prophecy": the problem may seem easier in an inadequate way because of the automatic labelling. In [my area](http://softclassval.r-forge.r-project.org/2011/2011-07-01-ABC-Glioma-paper.html), the resulting optimistic bias in validation would be unacceptable. This may be less dramatic in your case.
Automatic labelling has a tendency to overestimate/overemphasize class separability. You need to keep this in mind when *interpreting* the class separability of semi-supervised models.

Comment: @Gaël_Laurans: sorry, I missed your comment - you were first.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to teach you model to predict something, you have to perform an exploratory analysis of your data. To do this you could try to aggregate your data. See [Human Activity Recognition Using Smartphones Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones) to look for insights on how you could do it.

After aggregation you could visualize your data using [t-SNE](http://mayer.pro/t-SNE-Samsung) technique which is useful for high-dimensional data and allows you to project it on two-dimensional space.

Below you could find results of visualization of already mentioned dataset ([source](http://mayer.pro/t-SNE-Samsung)):
[image]

Comment: As I mentioned I have a lot of unlabeled data. T-SNE assumes that the dataset is already labeled by the expert.

Comment: You don't need labels to visualize your data, in the example above, labels were used only to paint points with different colors. In your case you'll see clusters of points where all the points will have same color. Then you might get some insights depending on what you see.